# Contact form sending but not receiving

Tags: php, forms, contacts

This is my first time asking something here so I hope I'm writing this post correctly.

I have this contact form at the end of this page (www.emilianomelchiorre.com) and, even if everything seems ok, I still don't receive any email. I don't know if the problem is in the code or maybe it's just the server.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        # FIX: Replace this email with recipient email
        $mail_to = "MYEMAIL@gmail.com";

        # Sender Data
        $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," ") , strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"])));
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($phone) OR empty($subject) OR empty($message)) {
            # Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        # Mail Content
        $content = "Name: $name\n";
        $content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $content .= "Phone: $phone\n";
        $content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        # email headers.
        $headers = "From: $name &lt;$email&gt;";

        # Send the email.
        $success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $content, $headers);
        if ($success) {
            # Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            # Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong, we couldn't send your message.";
        }

        } else {
            # Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
            http_response_code(403);
            echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
        }
?>
```

I'm not really sure about this part of the code, maybe something doesn't match. I really would like any kind of help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any error you are receiving?

Comment: Nothing. When I send a email I receive the feedback that everything worked correctly but still can't find anything in my inbox

Comment: Can you check spam also?

Comment: I did. I can't find anything anywhere

Comment: I've got always trouble sending automated mails to gmail. I suggest using your own email-address if you have one.

Comment: You can follow this link as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail

Comment: I'll try with my own email-address and let's see if something changes

Comment: Ok so quick update, I tried with my own email address and I receive that. so the problem is gmail. This is unfortunate since I check my gmail address more